# How do I get my code to not put a tab at the end, and instead end with just a newline

Tags: c, debugging

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

   int n;
   int f=0;
   
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("%d\t",n);
    
    while(n != 1) {

        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            n = n / 2;
        }
        else {
            n = (n * 3) + 1;
        }
        if (f == 9) {
            printf("\n%d\t", n);
        }
        else {
            printf("%d\t", n);
        } 
        f = (f + 1) % 10;
        
    }
    printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```

at the end, my code will keep a tab as the last key entered.  is there a way to just end with a newline for the last number?

Comment: Output the tab *before* the number instead. Or format with `"%8d"` and don't use tab (which is a blunt tool anyway belonging to teletypewriter days, or useful for text file formatting).

Comment: If you just want a newline every 10th item, then `printf("%8d", n); if(++f == 10) { f = 0; printf("\n"); }`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to print 10 numbers per line.  So you want the first 9 numbers to be followed by `\t`, but the tenth number to be followed by `\n` (and no `\t`).

So in pseudocode you have

```
for(some numbers) {
    if(one through nine)
         printf("%d\t", the_number);
    else printf("%d\n", the_number);
}
```

In C this might look like

```
f = 1;
while(n != 1) {

    /* ... */

    if(f % 10 != 0)
         printf("%d\t", n);
    else printf("%d\n", n);

    f++;
}
```

Of if you want to show off some leet C skillz:

```
while(n != 1) {
    /* ... */
    printf("%d%c", n, ++f % 10 == 0 ? '\n' : '\t');
}
```